# View animation massive lag

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I've written a method that animate an ImageView when it is clicked. 
It works, but between the start of the method and the moment it actually animates the view I have a delay that goes from 30ms to 4000ms. The very first time I click the image it take 30-50ms, the subsequent times it take 1000-4000ms to start the animation.

I'm trying to make a chain of animations, so face_out calls face_in in its onAnimationEnd callback. face_in has a variable delay, taken from the duration of the sound that play when face_out finishes. Also, if choise is a particular int, before face_in, parkour_anim is called. This animation just rotate the imageview by 360 degrees, the on it's onAnimationEnd it reset the rotation, but it doesn't work well.

```
private void onFaceClicked() {
    Log.d("CLICK", "Face clicked");

    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    vibrator.vibrate(50);
    choise = 0;

    if(period == Constants.A){
        choise = new Random().nextInt(Constants.CHOISES_A-1);
    }else{
        if (period == Constants.B){
            choise = new Random().nextInt(Constants.CHOISES_B-1);
        }
        else{
            choise = 0;
        }
    }


    ivFace.setEnabled(false);

    //FACE_OUT
    ivFace.animate().scaleX(2f).scaleY(2f)
    .setDuration(Constants.FACE_OUT_ANIMATION)
    .setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator())
    .setListener(new AnimatorListener() {
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            Log.d("ANIM", "Face_out started after: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
            imageViewAnimatedChange(ivFace,facesDrawables[choise]);
        }
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Log.d("ANIM", "Face_out ended after: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));

            if(choise == Constants.PARKOUR){
                Log.d("ANIM", "Parkour_anim started after: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
                ivFace.animate().rotationBy(360f).setDuration(sounds[choise].durationInMillis).setListener(new AnimatorListener() {                     
                    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {ivFace.setRotation(0);}
                    @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
                });
            }
            soundPool.play(sounds[choise].soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            //FACE_IN
            ivFace.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f)
            .setDuration(Constants.FACE_OUT_ANIMATION)
            .setStartDelay(sounds[choise].durationInMillis + 100)
            .setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator())
            .setListener(new AnimatorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    Log.d("ANIM", "Face_in started after: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
                    imageViewAnimatedChange(ivFace, facesDrawables[3]);
                }

                @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
                @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    Log.d("ANIM", "Face_in ended after: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));

                    ivFace.setEnabled(true);
                }

                @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
            });
        }

        @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
    });


}
```

What can cause such massive delay?

Update: The rootview contains other views that are animated as well (variable number, between 3 and 5).